# How to store Date values as integers into SQLite using QSqlTableModel

Tags: qt, sqlite, date, datetime, qsqltablemodel

I am trying to store Date values from Qt application into SQLite database as integers.

I have created date delegate with these functions implemented:

```
QWidget* DateDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
    const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  QDateTimeEdit* editor = new QDateTimeEdit(parent);
  editor->setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
  editor->setCalendarPopup(true);
  editor->setDateTime(QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch(index.data().toLongLong()*86400));
  return (editor);
}

void DateDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* paramEditor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  QDateTimeEdit* editor = static_cast<QDateTimeEdit*>(paramEditor);
  editor->setDateTime(QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch(index.data().toLongLong()*86400));
}

void DateDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *paramEditor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  QDateTimeEdit *editor = static_cast<QDateTimeEdit *>(paramEditor);
  model->setData(index, editor->dateTime().toSecsSinceEpoch()/86400);
}
```

And SubClassed model DTModel with only data() reimplemented:

```
QVariant DTModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role!=Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
    }
    if (index.column() != fieldIndex("datnaskld")) {
        return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
    }
    QVariant value = QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch(QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role).toInt()*86400).toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    return value;
}
```

Numbers are displayed corectly as dates.

But I have problem:
When field is entered to edit mode, date is always changed to the 01.01.1970 (means 0 internally)

What is missing here?..

Another problem is that setItemDelegateForColumn() is not working as expected. I have this command in the code:

```
ui->tableViewP->setItemDelegateForColumn(m->fieldIndex("datnaskld"), new DateDelegate(ui->tableViewP));
```

But delegate is assigned to all columns, not only to specified column. So I added these weird commands into delegate:

```
if (index.column() != fieldIndex("datnaskld")) {
     return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you query the model data from `DateDelegate::setEditorData()` function with `Qt::DisplayRole` (default) and try to convert it to long. However your model returns a string data for `Qt::DisplayRole`. This is inconsistent and leads to what you get.

Comment: What type of field is datnaskld?

Comment: @vahancho, not true. long is converted to QVariant(DateTime) by this:
QVariant value = QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch(.....

Comment: @eyllanesc, type is INT, but it is SQLite, so... hmm..

Comment: @lucky62 I was thinking of giving you another simpler solution with QItemEditorFactory, if you want me to do it please share me the .db.

Comment: I found also this factory example [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-coloreditorfactory-example.html]. But I think it is not simpler. The problem is that delegate is only for editing (unless the paint() method is redefined). So model must be subclassed anyway..

Comment: @lucky62 On the other hand if `data()` returns QDateTime it is not necessary to establish a new delegate, by default Qt will use QDateTimeEdit.

Comment: @eyllanesc, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution based on what I learned [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html).

Now my understanding to roles is much better.

I moved all calculations to the model, and DateDelegate is the "pure" editor. Model returns QString for Qt::DisplayRole and QDateTime for Qt::EditRole.

Date delegate implementation:

```
QWidget* DateDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,
                                    const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                                    const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QDateTimeEdit* editor = new QDateTimeEdit(parent);
    editor->setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    editor->setCalendarPopup(true);
    return (editor);
}

void DateDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QDateTimeEdit* ed = static_cast<QDateTimeEdit*>(editor);
    ed->setDateTime(index.data(Qt::EditRole).toDateTime());
}

void DateDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QDateTimeEdit *ed = static_cast<QDateTimeEdit *>(editor);
    model->setData(index, ed->dateTime(),Qt::EditRole);
}
```

DTModel implementation:

```
QVariant DTModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role!=Qt::DisplayRole && role!=Qt::EditRole) {
        return QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index,role);
    }
    if (index.column() != fieldIndex("datnaskld")) {
        return QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index,role);
    }

    QVariant value = QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index, role);
    if (role==Qt::EditRole) {
        value = QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch((value.toLongLong()-25569)*86400);
    } else {
        value = QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch((value.toLongLong()-25569)*86400).toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    }
    return value;
}

bool DTModel::setData(const QModelIndex &item, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (item.column() != this->fieldIndex("datnaskld")) {
        return QSqlRelationalTableModel::setData(item,value,role);
    }
    QVariant v = value.toDateTime().toSecsSinceEpoch()/86400+25569;
    return QSqlRelationalTableModel::setData(item,v,role);
};
```

I am adding/subtracting 25569 days to get the same numbers as MS Excel is using internally for Date. BTW I found the bug in MS Excel - seams that year 1900 is considered as leap year.. So for number 60 Qt shows 1.3.1900 but in Excel 29.2.1900 and all older dates are wrong in excel.